# How to implement a simple Scrollbar

Tags: c#, mathematics, user-interface

I'm making a simple UI system for a small game and i'm having some difficulty to implement a *Scrollbar*.

At the moment i'm having two major problems that i need some help to solve:

**.** Calculating the **"Value"** property of the *Scrollbar* when the current position of the *Thumb* on the *Track* is changed.

**.** Calculating the **"Minimum"** and **"Maximum"** properties to limit the position of the *Thumb* on the *Track*.

Below is part of the code that i currently have.
Please, look at the commented blocks.

```
public int Minimum  { get; set; }
public int Maximum  { get; set; }

public int Value    { get; set; }

public void Update()
{
    // Calculate the Scrollbar Thumb height:
    var viewable_ratio = ViewportHeight / ContentHeight;
    var scrollbar_area = ViewportHeight - ( ArrowHeight * 2 );
    
    this.ThumbHeight = scrollbar_area * viewable_ratio;
    
    // Calculate the Scrollbar Thumb step:
    var track_space = ContentHeight  - ViewportHeight;
    var thumb_space = ViewportHeight - ThumbHeight;
    
    this.ThumbStep = track_space / thumb_space;
    
    // TODO: Calculate the "Minimum" and "Maximum" values.
    this.Minimum = ???
    this.Maximum = ???
    
    Point mouse = Input.MousePosition();
    
    if(Thumb.Rectangle.Contains(mouse) && Input.MouseDown(0))
    {
        int x = Thumb.Position.x;
        int y = ( mouse.y - Thumb.Position.y );
        
        Thumb.Position = new Point(x, y);
        
        if(Thumb.Position.y < Minimum) Thumb.Position.y = Minimum;
        if(Thumb.Position.y > Maximum) Thumb.Position.y = Maximum;
        
        // TODO: Set the "Value" property to the correct value when the Thumb is moved.
        this.Value = ???
        this.Content.Position.y = this.Value;
    }
}
```

The **"Value"** property is used to scroll the **Content** and represent his position in the *Scrollbar*.

The **"Minimum"** and **"Maximum"** properties are used to not let the *Thumb* move outside of the *Track*.

Could someone please provide a direct answer with the math to calculate the scrollbar *Value*, *Minimum* and *Maximum* properties?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: It looks like that comment was meant to be part of your question. If so, please click the "edit" button, not the "add comment" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give values to `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Value` from the way you want to use them.

We start with this code, where you use `Minimum` and `Maximum`:

```
if(Thumb.Position.y < Minimum) Thumb.Position.y = Minimum;
if(Thumb.Position.y > Maximum) Thumb.Position.y = Maximum;
```

It appears that `Minimum` and `Maximum` should be actual positions on screen. In that case your `Minimum` is going to be `ArrowHeight`, and your `Maximum` is going to be `ViewportHeight - ArrowHeight - this.ThumbHeight`.

---

As per `Value`, you want to use it like this:

```
this.Content.Position.y = this.Value;
```

We need to transform `Thumb.Position` to a get the value that `this.Content.Position.y` should have… What do we know?

- When `Thumb.Position.y` is `Minimum`, `this.Content.Position.y` should be `0`.
- When `Thumb.Position.y` is `Maximum`, `this.Content.Position.y` should be `ViewportHeight - ContentHeight` a.k.a `-track_space`.
- It is a linear transformation. I.e. `this.Content.Position.y = Thumb.Position.y * factor + offset`.

*I'm assuming that the positive y goes downwards, and thus when you scroll down, you need give a negative position to the content so it moves upwards.*

Thus, we have two unknowns: `factor` and `offset`. And two linear equations:

```
Minimum * factor + offset = 0

Maximum * factor + offset = -track_space
```

Solve the system. *If my assumptions are wrong, you should still be able to come up with an equation system to solve.*

I'm feeling substitution:

```
Minimum * factor + offset = 0

=>

offset = -Minimum * factor

=>

Maximum * factor + -Minimum * factor = -track_space

=>

factor * (Maximum - Minimum) = -track_space

=>

factor = -track_space / (Maximum - Minimum)

=>

factor = track_space / (Minimum - Maximum)
```

And thus:

```
var factor = track_space / (Minimum - Maximum);
var offset = -Minimum * factor;
this.Value = Thumb.Position.y * factor + offset;
this.Content.Position.y = this.Value;
```

---

By the way, if I understand correctly, you are checking if the user is clicking on the `Thumb`:

```
if(Thumb.Rectangle.Contains(mouse) && Input.MouseDown(0))
{
   ...
}
```

And moving it:

```
int x = Thumb.Position.x;
int y = ( mouse.y - Thumb.Position.y );
        
Thumb.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

Which means that just clicking on the `Thumb` will make it move.

However, I believe that if the user is just clicking there you should do nothing! Instead you need to handle drag. And change `Thumb.Position` according to that drag.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for answering my question, it took me a while to understand everything but i think my problem is solved now. Thank you again!